# How to view the logs of a container?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm having a Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

ENV container docker

RUN yum -y update && yum -y install net-tools && yum -y install initscripts && yum -y install epel-release && yum -y install nginx && yum clean all
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# expose Nginx ports http/https
EXPOSE 80 443

RUN curl https://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html > /usr/share/nginx/index.html
RUN mv /usr/share/nginx/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html -f

RUN mkdir -p /local/nginx
RUN touch /local/nginx/start.sh
RUN chmod 755 /local/nginx/start.sh
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /local/nginx/start.sh
RUN echo "nginx" >> /local/nginx/start.sh
RUN echo "tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log" >> /local/nginx/start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/local/nginx/start.sh"]
```

I'm building it with `docker build -t "my_nginx" .`

And then running it with `docker run -i -t --rm -p 8888:80 --name nginx "my_nginx"`

https://localhost:8888/ shows the page but no logging is shown.

- If I press Ctrl-C, nginx is stopped but the tail on the logging is shown.
- If I press Ctrl-C again, the container is gone.

**Question: How can I let nginx run AND show the tail on the logging (which is preferably also visible using the "docker logs"-command)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is just to use the [Docker Hub `nginx` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), which deals with this for you.  A Dockerfile that could be as little as

```sh
FROM nginx:1.19
# Specifically use ADD because it will fetch a URL
ADD https://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

If you look at [its Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/9774b522d4661effea57a1fbf64c883e699ac3ec/mainline/buster/Dockerfile) it actually uses symbolic links to cause Nginx's "normal" logs to go to the container stdout

```sh
# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

That gets around most of the mechanics in your Dockerfile: you can just run `nginx` as the main container command without trying to use a second process to cat logs.  You can basically trim out the entire last half, and get

```sh
FROM centos:7

ENV container docker

RUN yum -y install epel-release \
 && yum -y install net-tools initscripts nginx \
 && yum clean all
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
 && ln -s /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
 && ln -s /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
RUN curl -o /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html https://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx"]
```

Yet another possibility here (with any of these images) is to mount your own volume over the container's `/var/log/nginx` directory.  That gives you your own host-visible directory of logs that you can inspect at your convenience.

```
mkdir logs
docker run -v $PWD/logs:/var/log/nginx -d ...
less logs/access.log
```

(In the shell script you construct in the Dockerfile, you use the Nginx `daemon off` directive to run as a foreground process, which means the `nginx` command will never exit on its own.  That in turn means the script never advances to the `tail` line, which is why you don't get logs out.)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `tail` command from the Dockerfile, run the container with `docker run -it -d --rm -p 8888:80 --name nginx "my_nginx"` and then use `docker logs -f nginx`.